# Set is discrete and closed; open mapping theorem.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

> $g:G \rightarrow G'$ is a holomorphic function of a region $G$ onto a region (open connected) $G'$. The zero set $N(g')$ of derivative of $g$ is discrete and closed in $G$. $g$ is open mapping implies the set, 
>   $$ M:= \{b \in G' \, : \, g^{-1}(b) \subseteq N(g') \}$$
>   is discrete and closed in $G'$. (Remmert p286).

I don't understand why openning mapping implies the result.

---

**Closed set:** Let $g(x)=z \in G' \setminus g(M)$.  Then exists $x$ such that $g'(x) \not= 0$. So there exists an nhood $U_x$ of $x$, such that for all $y \in U_x$, $g'(y) \not= 0$ by continuity. As $g$ is not locally constant, $g(U_x)$ is an open set containing $z$, and $g(U_x) \cap g(M) = \emptyset$ (if $w \in g(U_x) \cap g(M)$, then $g^{-1}(w) \not \subseteq N(g')$).

Comment: If $g(x)=z \in G'\setminus g(M)$ does not imply that $g'(x) \neq 0$.

If $g(x)=z \in g(M)$ implies that $g'(x) = 0$.

If $g(x)=z \in G'\setminus g(M)$ then $\exists x $ such that $g'(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: @trying, yes thank you. I believe this doesn't affect the proof?

Comment: yes, indeed. In the end your proof of the closedness of $M$ is correct even though it does not make explicit use of the openness of $g$. But following the same pattern as that of your proof, you can substitute: [As $g$ is open, $g(U_x)$ is an neighborhood of z, ...] for [As $g$ is not locally constant, $g(U_x)$ is an open set containing $z$,...], because open maps preserve neighborhoods.

Answer (score 0):

The zero set of any non-constant holomorphic function on a region $G$ is discrete, i.e. all zeros are isolated.  If $b \in M$, take some $z \in g^{-1}(b)$.  Then $g'(z) = 0$.  If $D$ is a sufficiently small open disk around $z$, $g'(z') \ne 0$ for all $z' \in D \backslash \{z\}$.  Now the Open Mapping Theorem says $g(D)$ is an open neighbourhood of $g(z) = b$, and for any $b' \in g(D) \backslash \{b\}$  we have $b' = g(z')$ for some $z' \in D \backslash \{z\}$, and $g'(z') \ne 0$ so $b' \notin M$.

Comment: Ok, I see that this shows discreteness as for each $b \in M$, $g(D) \cap M = \{b \}$. But how does this show that $M$ is closed?

Comment: I have added what I think suffices to prove closeness of $M$ (which is almost the same proof), is it right?